# Connecting a wireless wimax modem to Huawei HG8245?

Tags: network-shares, wireless-networking, adsl, internet-connection

I have a Fiber optics ADSL connection which is connected to a Huawei HG8245 modem. Its IP is 192.168.100.1. I have given my friend a connection from that modem though a cat 5 cable and he wants to create a WIFI Zone in his home.

So, I gave my old SAGEM 2804 ADSL modem to connect the cable in to it directly thinking to use it as an wireless switch. But it shut off my wireless now. If he connects my wifi is getting shut down. The sagem 2804 router and modem are in the same IP range (192.168.100.10).

Comment: To clarify your understanding of your internet connection, you don't have a "fiber optics ADSL". Like all DSL circuits, it runs over copper from your house to the local CO, and from there it hops onto your provider's fiber ring.

Comment: He might have FTTH, in which case there's no copper and it is billed by the telco as "DSL."

Comment: k..i agree on your opinion..but thats not the issue here ip conflict because of dhcp..in both of the device im using...please can u give a solution for that...

Answer (score 0):

The router in your friend's home should have a different address range. Change it to 192.168.11.X or something.

Change the router's wireless broadcast to a different channel than one the modem is using.

Turn off authentication (using a modem as a router can cause problems because it's trying to authenticate rather than just be a bridge).

Comment: I'm a sister, but you're welcome. ;-)